# Can I access a folder on client side in web application?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I want to access all the files in a folder to add to a listbox and show to the user.

I know I can access a folder when it's a windows application. But in web application, is this possible? If yes, how?

Something like FolderBrowserDialog??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically no, but you can create an active x control to be installed on the user end that will communicate on your page and list the files.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think You do that using JavaScript.if that what u meant active x control and java applet is a way to go